# How to determine the angle of rotation for a rotating/animating cylinder? Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm stuck on this and my Math skills are failing. I've set up a working [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/aro6fyh3/1/).

I have been able to extract the y and z positions from the rotating cylinder and am able to stop the animation when the number 1 is in view. I'm doing that by using this ugly method:

```
if (p > 75 && p < 90 && pp > 155 && pp < 165){
```

On observing the y and z values I noticed that the values change quite considerable (try running the sample multiple times) and I had to check for a certain range.

As I'm having 8 faces on the cylinder I was hoping to simply extract the number of the face which is in "front" (or facing a certain direction). Or maybe check for the angle the cylinder is in during the rotation. I have no idea how for instance I could output the angle during animation.

If anyone can give me a clue that would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5vxvLdub/3/

Relevant portion:

```
    function fuzzyEqual( n1, n2 ) {
        var epsilon = .01;
        return ( n1 - epsilon < n2 ) && ( n1 + epsilon > n2 );
    }

    var desiredNum = 3,
        faces = 8,
        theta = Math.PI * 2 * ( faces - desiredNum - 5.5 ) / faces,
        destY = Math.cos( theta ),
        destZ = Math.sin( theta );

    // request new frame
    requestAnimationFrame(function(){
        // ugly method :p
        if ( fuzzyEqual( o.y, destY ) && fuzzyEqual( o.z, destZ ) ){
            return;
        }
        animate(time);
    });
```

Comment: Oh my word you did it! (Now I need to put the image on properly as it's upside down now) I'm going to have to study your code (lot's of stuff I have forgotten, school was +30 years ago). Thank you very much! :)

Comment: No problem.  My first version forgot to account for it rotating in the opposite direction.  I've corrected it so that you can change `desiredNum` and still get the correct result.